# Customize Custom Cell further

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have the following class that generate custom cell. It works very well. However, I have a condition where I need to get more space for my InfoLabel than it is defined below. I could not able to handle it?

```
public WeinerGeneralCellItem (NSString cellId, Short Weiner) : base     (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        this.Weiner = Weiner;

        weinerInfoLabel = new UILabel () {
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (0, 0, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
        };

        weinerInfo = new UITextField () {
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (0, 0, 0),
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
        };

        ContentView.Add (weinerInfoLabel);
        ContentView.Add (weinerInfo);   
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        weinerInfoLabel.Frame = new CGRect(20, ContentView.Bounds.Height/4, 200, 25);
        weinerInfo.Frame = new CGRect(220, ContentView.Bounds.Height/4, 300, 25);
    }
}
```

By default infolabel width is 200, info is 300, but for the last cell, I want infoLabel width is 350, info is 150. I have tried the following but it did not work.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath  indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Row == 5) {
      cell.weinerInfoLabel.Frame = new CGRect(20, 20, 350, 25);
      cell.weinerInfo.Frame = new CGRect(350, 20, 150, 25);
      cell.weinerInfoLabel.Text = "The value calculated from the server";
      cell.weinerInfo.Tag = 5;
      cell.weinerInfo.Text = "155.00";  
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using a different Id for the 5th cell?  Otherwise the caching mechanism will treat every cell the same.

Comment: You need to account for the difference in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because this is the method that knows about rows. The cell itself doesn't. You can invoke a method on the cell object to have it configure itself from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I assign a tag  as follow cell.winerinfo.Tag =5

Comment: @Paulw11, could you please give an example ? It is not quite clear at the moment.

Comment: You need to `if indexpath.row == 5` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and inside that if you can say something like `cell.expandRow()` where the `expandRow` function is the code you have to change the frames. Don't forget to call another function to set the field frames to normal size in the `else` clause to account for cell reuse

Comment: Actually, that piece of code is already inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. check my updated question. `GetCell` method in the Xamarin corresponds to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in objective-c

Comment: @Jason, I have updated my question, hope it is clear.

Comment: If you do this only, because the content of cell 5 needs more space: What is your minimum supported iOS version? If its >= iOS 8, you should have a look at dynamic cell heights. Then you don't have to deal with Frames anymore :)

Comment: Could you please provide more details, I only support >= 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I have ended up, it is working. I am just checking `tag` id before setting up the frame for that corresponding cell.

```
public override void LayoutSubviews ()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews ();
    if (weinerInfo.Tag == 5) 
    {
       weinerInfoLabel.Frame = new CGRect (20, ContentView.Bounds.Height / 4, 350, 25);
       weinerInfo.Frame = new CGRect (350, ContentView.Bounds.Height / 4, 170, 25);
    } 
    else 
    {
        weinerInfoLabel.Frame = new CGRect(20, ContentView.Bounds.Height/4, 200, 25);
        weinerInfo.Frame = new CGRect (220, ContentView.Bounds.Height / 4, 300, 25);
    }
}
```